# Spring Boot Thin Jar, How To?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, packaging

I want to use thin jar created by Spring Boot Maven Plugin (jarname.jar.original). I got all dependencies in lib directory. Tried to run. But it is giving following exception related to Banner. I tried to switch it off using spring.main.banner_mode=off. Why it is so obscure information about Spring boot thin jar ? I did not find any useful by googling.

```
java -cp 'target/thin-jar-0.1.0.jar:target/lib/*' com.example.cloudpayables.api.Application
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.showBanner(Z)Lorg/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder;
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace? Whatever's calling `showBanner` has been compiled against one version of Spring Boot and is running against another version.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the maven-dependency-plugin to make sure you are capturing all the required dependencies for your project. What I am guessing is missing is some transitive dependency.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html

[Josh Long](https://twitter.com/starbuxman?lang=en) will be very sad that the banner isn't showing and is causing the problem in your situation. :)